# Will SystemEvents.TimeChanged leak if a winforms application is closed without detaching its event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On the one hand, [the event's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  say

> ... you must detach your event handlers when your application is
>   disposed, or memory leaks will result.

On the other hand, [its class's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   say:

> does not affect desktop applications

So is the event's documentation simply relying on the class's? Or will it leak from a Winforms application as well?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question or the relevance of the second excerpt, but from the event's documentation it does appear that failure to detach your event handlers will cause memory leaks.

Comment: The second link says that the HostProtectionAttribute doesn't apply, not that the host is immune to leaks simply because it doesn't apply. I'd assume that you're meant to properly dispose of all static resources, since they are shared across processes, and very well may introduce leaks.

Comment: Depends how you declare it.  If you added the timer through the designer, then you don't have to worry about disposing it.  If the timer was declared through a *local* method (the scope is not at the class level), then you will have potential issues.

Comment: You cannot "leak" SystemEvents, it is a static class.  You can certainly leak your Form object when you don't unsubscribe the event, it will never be garbage-collected because SystemEvents has a reference to it.

Comment: @HansPassant Your comment seemed to close the matter. However, I now noticed that the first quote I brought in the question (from the event's docs) says "you must detach your event handlers **when your application is disposed**" [emphasis mine] - how would there be a memory leak if the application is disposed? Is it a memory leak in Windows (the OS) because it's still trying to inform a nonexistent application of an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line: see [this comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751543/will-systemevents-timechanged-leak-if-a-winforms-application-is-closed-without-d#comment45788418_28751543) - The **Form** won't get GC'd if it's referenced by `SystemEvents`.